# Spring @ConditionalOnBean in combination with @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Having the next situation:

```java
@ConditionalOnBean(ServiceD.class)
@Component
class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

    private ServiceB serviceB;
    private ServiceC serviceC;
    private ServiceD serviceD;

    public ServiceA(ServiceB serviceB, ServiceC serviceC, ServiceD serviceD) {
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
        this.serviceC = serviceC;
        this.serviceD = serviceD;
    }
}

interface ServiceD {

    void doStuff();
}

@Component
class ServiceDImpl implements ServiceD {

    private ServiceE serviceE;

    public ServiceD(ServiceE serviceE) {
        this.serviceE = serviceE;
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        //...
    }
}
```

I need serviceA to be loaded only if there exists a serviceD implementation.

From `@ConditionalOnBean` documentation: *"The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only."*.

My question is:
As **ServiceD** is a dependency of **ServiceA**, will this guarantee that when `@ConditionalOnBean` is evaluated, **ServiceD** will be already processed by the application context?

If not, is there any other way to acomplished that without using autoconfiguration classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue. There is no guarantee that ServiceD bean would be created before ServiceA, as you cannot change the order of bean registration from `@ComponentScan`. It's why the documentation says to use the condition on auto-configuration classes only. So you either have to make ServiceA auto-configured, so that all your other defined beans are defined before ServiceA bean, or use a different annotation such as `@ConditionalOnClass`.

Answer (score 0):

By default `Spring` manages beans' lifecycle and arranges their initialization order.

But, we can still customize it based on our needs. We can choose either the SmartLifeCycle interface or the `@DependsOn` annotation for managing initialization order.

You can try `@DependsOn` By using this annotation for specifying bean dependencies. Spring guarantees that the defined beans will be initialized before attempting an initialization of the current bean. Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As `@DependsOn` documentation specifies: ** Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.**
In my case, ServiceD depends on ServiceA through constructor. Do I need to explicity use `@DependsOn`?

Comment: It still isn't clear for me if I need `@DependsOn` even if ServiceD depends on ServiceA through constructor?

Comment: you should try it at least by removing the constructor dependency

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I ve accepted  夢のの夢 answer as it fits my case and is the solution I ve chosen.